# Change a while true python script to run only once

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to python and I want this code to run only once and stops, not every 30 seconds

because I want to run multiple codes like this with different access tokens every 5 seconds using the command line.
and when I tried this code it never jumps to the second one because it's a while true:

```
import requests
import time

api_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/"
access_token = "access token"
graph_url = "site url"
post_data = { 'id':graph_url, 'scrape':True, 'access_token':access_token }
# Beware of rate limiting if trying to increase frequency.
refresh_rate = 30 # refresh rate in second

while True:
    try:
        resp = requests.post(api_url, data = post_data)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            contents = resp.json()
            print(contents['title'])
        else:
            error = "Warning: Status Code {}\n{}\n".format(
                resp.status_code, resp.content)
            print(error)
            raise RuntimeWarning(error)
    except Exception as e:
        f = open ("open_graph_refresher.log", "a")
        f.write("{} : {}".format(type(e), e))
        f.close()
        print(e)
    time.sleep(refresh_rate)
```

Comment: How're passing multiple access token to this code? If you don't want `while true` remove that and make it a function and call the function passing different access tokens every 5 seconds in another function call.

Comment: no, I'm not trying to add multiple access tokens in one file but multiple files that runs this codes only once and then call all the files in the command line using the sleep 5 command 
`while true; do sleep 5;`

Comment: I am not quite getting. Let me rephrase, are you executing this piece of code for every other access tokens?

Comment: Yes  thats what I'm trying to do using this command: 

`while true; do sleep 5; python3 access1.py;
sleep 5; python3 access2.py;
sleep 5; python3 access3.py;
sleep 5; python3 access4.py;
sleep 5; python3 access5.py; done &`

and the code inside every python file should execute only once to let the next file to execute and so on...

Comment: Did you get any error log? Your `while true; ...` I presume is shell command. Correct me, if otherwise.

Comment: No only the first python file that executes and not letting the other ones run because it's an infinite loop. and I need to change that in every code in every file.

Comment: Your `access1.py access2.py...` all have unique `access_tokens`?

Comment: yes that's true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood you're trying to execute the piece of code for multiple access tokens. To make your job simple, have all your `access_tokens` as lists and use the following code. It assumes that you know all your `access_tokens` in advance.

```
import requests
import time

def scrape_facebook(api_url, access_token, graph_url):
    """ Scrapes the given access token"""
    post_data = { 'id':graph_url, 'scrape':True, 'access_token':access_token }

    try:
        resp = requests.post(api_url, data = post_data)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            contents = resp.json()
            print(contents['title'])
        else:
            error = "Warning: Status Code {}\n{}\n".format(
                resp.status_code, resp.content)
            print(error)
            raise RuntimeWarning(error)
    except Exception as e:
        f = open (access_token+"_"+"open_graph_refresher.log", "a")
        f.write("{} : {}".format(type(e), e))
        f.close()
        print(e)

access_token = ['a','b','c']
graph_url = ['sss','xxx','ppp']
api_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/"

for n in range(len(graph_url)):
    scrape_facebook(api_url, access_token[n], graph_url[n])
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: This works. but I need a delay of 5 seconds between every scrape

Comment: I have added a `5` second `sleep` between every execution. Now it should be fine.

Comment: When you post your question, try to post all the relevant details so that for those who want to help it would be easy. Welcome to SO!! Find time to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask